# NHibernate + Fluent NHibernate exception

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

**Problem**:

There are searches that can be stored in the DB. Each search has a collection of filters. Also there are roles. Each role may have (nullable column) a default search assigned to it. Also, each search is visible to zero or many roles (many-to-many relationship).

When I try to access the search filters, NH tries to access filters.DefaultSearchId, which doesn't exist in filters table.

**DB:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Searches]
(
    Id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    Description nvarchar(2000) not null
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Filters]
(
    Id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    Description nvarchar(2000) not null,
    SearchId int not null references Searches(Id)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Roles]
(
    Id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    Name nvarchar(255) not null,
    DefaultSearchId int null references Searches(Id)
);
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SearchesRoles]
(
    SearchId int not null references Searches(Id),
    RoleId int not null references Roles(Id)
);
```

**Entities:**

```
  public class Search {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Filter> Filters { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    }

    public class Filter {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual Search Search { get; set; }
    }

    public class Role {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual Search DefaultSearch { get; set; }
    }
```

**Mappings:**

```
 public class SearchMap : ClassMap<Search>{
        public SearchMap() {
            Table("Searches");
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
            Map(x => x.Description);
            HasMany(x => x.Filters).Inverse().Cascade.All().AsBag();
            HasManyToMany(x => x.Roles).Table("SearchesRoles").ParentKeyColumn("SearchId").ChildKeyColumn("RoleId");
        }
    }

 public class FilterMap : ClassMap<Filter> {
        public FilterMap() {
            Table("Filters");
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
            Map(x => x.Description);
            References(x => x.Search).Column("SearchId");
        }
    }
 public class RoleMap : ClassMap<Role> {
        public RoleMap() {
            Table("Roles");
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
            Map(x => x.Name);
            References(x => x.DefaultSearch).Column("DefaultSearchId");
        }
    }
```

**Code:**

```
class Program {
        static void Main() {
            var sessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory();
            using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession()) {
                var search = session.Get<Search>(1);
                foreach (var filter in search.Filters) {
                    Console.WriteLine(filter);
                }
            }
        }

        static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory(){
            string connectionString = @"server=.\sql2008; user id = sa; pwd=1; database = nhbug;";
            return Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(connectionString))
                .Mappings(m=>m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())).BuildSessionFactory();
        }
    }
```

**ERROR:**

When accessing the *search.Filters* property, NHibernate tries to access *Filters.DefaultSearchId* db column which is not supposed to be there. This column exists in Roles table but not in filters.

**QUESTION:**

Is it invalid configuration, Fluent NHibernate or NHibernate bug?

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2, NHibernate 2.1.2 and Fluent NHibernate 1.1.0.685, although this issue exists in NHibernate 3 beta 2 as well.

Thank you.

UPDATE:
Here is the [actual SQL](https://gist.github.com/703732) generated

UPDATE2: CDMDOTNET, same error, same sql, unfortunately.

UPDATE3: [Actual exception](https://gist.github.com/704778)

UPDATE4: This is a particular use case of a general bug: Entity references other entities as 'many-to-many' and on the other side of 'many-to-many' assoc. the other entity references the source entity (DefaultQuery in my case). NH goes nuts when accessing **any** child collection (one-to-many) of a source entity (Filters in my case).

UPDATE5: [Sample data](https://gist.github.com/704788)

UPDATE6: [XML issued by Fluent NHibernate](https://gist.github.com/704790)

Comment: Could you post the generated SQL queries too?

Comment: Out of curiousity what happens for you when you add ".Cascade.None( )" to the References(x => x.DefaultSearch).Column("DefaultSearchId");
and ".AsSet()" in stead of ".AsBag()" on the HasMany(x => x.Filters).Inverse().Cascade.All().AsBag();

Comment: Can you post the actual error?

Comment: I get a different error running your code with NH3 Beta 2. "SELECT filters0_.Search_id as Search4_1_" tries to get "Search_id"?!?

Comment: How do I see the actual XML generated by Fluent? I would like to find out if it is a NH bug or Fluent NH bug.

Comment: Can you give some test data? I can successfully run the code in NH3/Beta2

Comment: @Valentin: You can use something like this in your config to get the xml files: .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<SomeMapping>().ExportTo(@"C:\\"))

Comment: user456813, it is weird that you can run the code on NH 3 beta 2. I've tried it but with same results. What about your previous error you had?

Comment: For the previous error I just specified the KeyColumn in the mapping. "HasMany(x => x.Filters).KeyColumn("SearchId").Inverse().Cascade.All().AsBag();" I haven't changed any of your code at all. My reference to Fluent NH3 was using NuGet. (might actually be beta 1, but that shouldn't matter). Maybe you're missing a reference to something?

Comment: I think I've found the error, it is Fluent generating invalid XML, see my update.

Comment: Ahh, you can fix that by adding the KeyColumn on the HasMany like my last comment. Must be Fluent getting confused with the Role mapping. Strange.

Comment: @user456831, please answer this question, and the bounty yours! It worked for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Should this be raised as a bug with FNH?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update the HasMany mapping on the SearchMap to include the KeyColumn():

HasMany(x => x.Filters)**.KeyColumn("SearchId")**.Inverse().Cascade.All().AsBag();

Comment: SO says that I may reward the bounty in 5 hours only, so will wait until then.

Comment: No problem, was fun to debug.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the column name for the Filters bag. It should be set to SearchId.